# New project build takes infinite time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

I updated my Android Studio yesterday to 2.3 version and the gradle to 3.3
i can open recent projects, but when i'm trying to create a new project it stuck on " build project... " for infinite time.
no error massages, nothing happens, just keep loading without doing anything

please help!

Comment: Not being funny, but did you try close and open Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, no change...

Comment: can you build the project from the command line? Try to call `./gradlew clean assemble`

Comment: Still no change, i tried re-install android studio but it also didn't helped i don know what to do....